# c++20 submodules: cannot compile

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++20, c++-modules

Linux, clang 16.0.6, cmake 3.26.x

Reading [this c++ modules article](https://www.zverovich.net/2023/04/17/simple-cxx20-modules.html), I succeded to compile and run the trivial example.
I decided to try modules partition, but it won't compile anymore:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

import mod1;
//import mod1:b;
auto main() -> int{

    std::cout << G2::tell_me_more() << std::endl;
    
}
```

**mod1.ixx**

```
module;

#include <string>
export module mod1;

export namespace G1 {
        
        auto tell_me () -> std::string {

                return "OK for me";
        }

}
```

**mod1b.ixx**

```
module;

#include <string>
export module mod1:b;

export namespace G2 {
        
        auto tell_me_more () -> std::string {
                G1::tell_me(); // <- error here
                return "OK for me 2";
        }

}
```

But I have the following error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'G1'
```

CmakeList:

```
...
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP 1)

include(modules.cmake)

add_module_library(mod1b src/mod1b.ixx )
add_module_library(mod1 src/mod1.ixx )

add_executable(${APP_NAME} main.cpp)
set_target_properties(${APP_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} mod1 mod1b)
...
```

I thought that modules could avoid having a "header" and an "implementation", but it seems that I need an interface here to declare G1.

Is there a way to solve this without a separate interface file?

#### Edit:

apparently, mod1b is compiled before mod1 ( I manually replaced the paths to simplify the reading):

```
Generating mod1b.pcm
[build] FAILED: mod1b.pcm path/mod1b.pcm 
[build] cd build_path && /usr/bin/clang++-16 -std=c++20 -x c++-module --precompile -c -o mod1b.pcm /my_path/src/mod1b.ixx
```

#### Edit 2:

taking into account all the comments so far, I tried this alternative, still no luck:

**mod1-b.ixx**

```
module;

#include <string>

export module mod1:b;

export namespace G2 {
        
        auto tell_me_more () -> std::string {
              
                return "OK for me 2";
        }

}
```

**mod1.ixx**

```
module;

#include <string>
export module mod1;
import :b; // error here, even with "export import :b"
export namespace G1 {

        auto tell_me () -> std::string {
                G2::tell_me_more(); //discard result, don't care here.

                return "OK for me";
        }

}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

import mod1;

auto main() -> int{


    std::cout << G1::tell_me() << std::endl;
    
}
```

But now the error is:

```
fatal error: module 'mod1:b' not found
```

Comment: Don't you need to `import mod1;` inside `mod1b.ixx`?

Comment: I just tried: same issue but I notice that the build system tries to compile mod1b before mod1

Comment: Don't know about clang/Cmake, but the MS compiler expects `mod1:b` to be found in a file named `mod1-b.ixx`

Comment: *I thought that modules could avoid having a "header" and an "implementation", but it seems that I need an interface here to declare G1* - I have no idea where you got that impression, but this is not true. The root cause of the problem here really is simply that your use case is not a good use case for interface partitions. As the name partition implies, they only work if you can clearly divide the module into independent parts. But fortunately there are plenty of other mechanisms for organizing code with modules that work much better for this case.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: clearly a misunderstanding of mine here

Comment: You need to say `export import :b`, not just `import`! Other than that your example is fine and I am unable to reproduce the error you have given with MSVC. You have probably triggered either one of the compiler bugs in clang's module implementation or one of the many limitations of the `add_module_library` hack. Also, please refrain from making substantial edits to existing questions like this. It invalidates existing answers and votes.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: you are right, and I will leave it there. I will wait for clang 17 and see what's next. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong use of module partition.

1. The primary module interface unit *must* export all module interface partitions ([[module.unit]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/module.unit#3.sentence-3)). Thus, `mod1.ixx` must import `mod1:b`, using `export import :b;`, but ...
2. In order to use `G1::tell_me` in `mod1b.ixx`, a declaration of `G1::tell_me` must be reachable. This means `mod1b.ixx` must import `mod1`.

... and that's an interface dependency cycle!

To break the cycle, you must reorganize you code so that the interface partition does not depend on the primary module interface unit.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the structure. I update the question. But still no luck

Comment: @Kroma: He said you have to `export import :b` in the primary interface unit. You didn't do that; you only `import`ed it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes, same thing, I did that but `fatal error: module 'mod1:b' not found [build] export import :b;` I update the commented line to reflect that

Comment: @Kroma: Does your build system know how to find partitions? Also, is your build system OK with filenames with dashes in them?

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes to all, I tried so many combinations. I am pretty sure, but may be wrong, that the hack I use is not compliant with partitions. But again, I may miss something else..

Comment: @Kroma: There is no hack involved; this is basic implementation partition usage. The most unusual thing about it is that you used a `-` character in your filename.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I just showed one of the variants I desperately tried. At the moment I am writing, the files are named `mod1_b.ixx`and `mod1.ixx`. As for the extension, I just took the one in the article; Not sure if it matters honestly. Didn't try yet